# PHP string split single dimensional array into two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, multidimensional-array

Morning All,

I currently have an array $files which when I run:

```
print_r($files);
```

The output is:

```
Array ( [0] => 62007-00-15.pdf [1] => 62007-15.pdf [2] => 62007-15SW.pdf [3] => 85080-00.pdf )
```

I would like to string split this using - as a delimiter array so it is still stored in a single array but with 3 parts. I am using the following code:

```
// STRING SPLIT FILENAME ARRAY
foreach($files as $key => $value) {
$stringsplit = explode('-', $key);
$new_array[] = array(
    'FPN1' => $stringsplit[0],
    'FPN2' => $stringsplit[1],
    'FDW' => $stringsplit[2]
);
}
```

But I am getting the following results:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [FPN1] => 0 [FPN2] => [FDW] => ) [1] => Array ( [FPN1] => 1 [FPN2] => [FDW] => ) [2] => Array ( [FPN1] => 2 [FPN2] => [FDW] => ) [3] => Array ( [FPN1] => 3 [FPN2] => [FDW] => ) )
```

If I perform a test for the explode function e.g.

```
// TEST STRING SPLIT FILENAME ARRAY
foreach($files as $key => $value) {
echo explode('-', $key);
}
```

I get the results:

```
ArrayArrayArrayArray
```

So I assume I am not performing the explode correctly? However I cant seem to get this to work!

Any help much appreciated

Thanks,

Bepster

Comment: Does this https://ideone.com/6540yx work for you the way you expect?

Answer (score 5):

Yours text are in VALUE not in KEY so

not `explode('-', $key);`

but `explode('-', $value);`

Comment: You are welcome :) I recommend you to learn a little about arrays and see what is what and where :) http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php It is very useful.